String is not a subtype of type Map
Error:
_TypeError (type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>' in type cast) 

Declaration
 final Map<dynamic, dynamic> jsonMap = jsonStr as Map;

jsonStr = [log] [{"title":"Google — Year in Search 2021","artist":"<unknown>","album":"Download"}]

SongModel class is a class belonging to the on_audio_query package,
Accepts data of type map
Future<void> _loadSonMusicList() async {
 final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
 final List<dynamic>? sonMusicListJson = prefs.getStringList(_sonMusicListKey);

if (sonMusicListJson != null && sonMusicListJson.isNotEmpty) {
   final List<SongModel> loadedSongs = [];

  for (String jsonStr in sonMusicListJson) {
    
    final Map<dynamic, dynamic> jsonMap = jsonStr as Map;
    final SongModel song = SongModel(jsonMap); 
    loadedSongs.add(song);

}

  _sonMusicListe = loadedSongs;
} else {
  _sonMusicListe = [];
}

   notifyListeners();
}


can you please try to print [print("jsonStr = $jsonStr")] it and show us the result? put this print before the cast.

The error has happened because the jsonStr is List and you are trying to cast it as Map, try this:
for (var jsonStr in sonMusicListJson) { //<=== change this
  var list = List.from(json.decode(jsonStr)); //<=== add this this
  if(list.isNotEmpty){ //<=== add this this
     final Map<dynamic, dynamic> jsonMap = list.first as Map;
     final SongModel song = SongModel(jsonMap); 
     loadedSongs.add(song);
  }
}


now it gives this error = _TypeError (type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>' in type cast)

@YusufBrly can you please try to print [print("jsonStr = $jsonStr")] it and show us the result? put this print before the cast.

jsonStr = [{"title":"Google — Year in Search 2021","artist":"","album":"Download"}]

The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable'.
@eamirho3ein

I updated my answer again @YusufBrly
